# Highchart - highstock scroll out of sync with zoom

Tags: highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I have a chart on which I am showing very small interval time data (close to 2 minutes), when I zoom In using drag at the `centre` of chart, the call to server gets the zoomed data but the at x-axis the navigator(horizontal scroll) moves the zoomed in data to `extreme left` it should have been in centre of time line.

```
Say for example timeline has interval in seconds as below

0---30---60---90---120
and I zoom in at 30 to 90
The navigator or scroll axis should have stayed at 0---120 and the focus part should be 30---90
but In my case it changing the navigator to 30 to 120 and focus area moves to extreme left.

Note: with bigger time intervals it works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

The navigator call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) function which set a range on any axis. Unfortunatley it is default behaviour and you cannot zoom chart partly.

Comment: so by saying you cannot zoom chart partly... that I can not zoom in by drag or by pulling the extremes of scrollbar ???